# CakePHP form helper problem with date for editing

Tags: cakephp, forms, helper

I'm quite newbie in CakePHP, I've tried to create a form with form helper on a date field

```
echo $this->Form->input('Item.date');
```

yes, works fine (I'm using CakePHP v1.3.3) for input/add new record but when I try using it on edit page it does nothing. here's the code

```
echo $this->Form->input('Item.date', array("value"=>$rs['Item']['date']));
```

it still display listbox without retrieving the value from desired table. Any help appreciated, sorry for my english..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you shouldnt use inline params for default values.
pass them down from the controller:

http://www.dereuromark.de/2010/06/23/working-with-forms/

see "default-values"

Answer (score 0):

I've found the answer, using selected option:

```
echo $this->Form->input('Item.date', array('selected'=>$rs['Item']['date']));
```

Comment: That's not a very good idea. Read the article in "mark"s answer.